# How to create a system call for FreeBSD kernel

Tags: operating-system, kernel, system-calls, freebsd

I want to add new syscall to freeBSD kernel and I want to change `syscalls.master` file in  `/usr/src/sys/kern/syscalls.master`. But this file is not existing in this path and `/usr/src` path is empty. What is wrong in this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to get the source. See the first step in [this document](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/makeworld.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first work for creating a system call is getting the source from svn.
The first step is to determine which version of FreeBSD is being used with `uname` command.

```
uname -r
```

I have `10.3-RELEASE` of freeBSD then I get this version from svn with the following command.

```
svnlite checkout https://svn.freebsd.org/base/releng/10.3 /usr/src
```